# multiply two numpy arrays to make a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got some output of my program, say

`a = [0.5  0.73  -0.48]`    (I don't see commas there, which I feel a bit weird)

`b = [0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5]`     (same as above)

I checked each by using type() and they were numpy.ndarray, I then use len() to verify their size and got 3 and 5 respectively. I also did shape to find that a is (3,) and b is (5,)

Now, I wonder how could I multiply these two to get a matrix of size 3 by 5?

I have tried so many ways and none has worked.

Comment: What is your expected result? Please include the code for your failed attempts.

Comment: A matrix of size 3 by 5. Basically I want to treat "a" as a 3 by 1 vector and "b" as a 1 by 5 vector, so a*b would give me a matrix of 3 by 5.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny This should be an answer

Comment: LOL. Sorry about that. Yeah, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the outer product:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.5, 0.73, -0.48])
b = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

result = np.outer(a, b)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```py
[[ 0.05 ,  0.1  ,  0.15 ,  0.2  ,  0.25 ],
[ 0.073,  0.146,  0.219,  0.292,  0.365],
[-0.048, -0.096, -0.144, -0.192, -0.24 ]]
```

Comment: That works too !! Thanks

Comment: It's basically what Tim Roberts posted, but as a numpy function (Which is faster because numpy is written in C and C++)

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see commas because those are numpy vectors.  Numpy displays its arrays without commas.

The "@" operator is matrix multiply.  The key is that you need to turn these into 2D arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.5, 0.73, -0.48])
b = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
result = a.reshape(3,1)@b.reshape(1,5)
print(result)
```

output:

```
[[ 0.05   0.1    0.15   0.2    0.25 ]
 [ 0.073  0.146  0.219  0.292  0.365]
 [-0.048 -0.096 -0.144 -0.192 -0.24 ]]
```

Comment: You rock !!! That solved the issue. thanks much